# Error en consulta JSOn flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
Future<List<Negocio>> fetchPost() async {
  print("requesting..");
  final response =
  await http.get('https://vivicarhue.000webhostapp.com/DBRemota/wsJSONConsultarNegocio.php?categoria=panaderia');
  //Revisamos si la respuesta es OK
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    //Listado de objetos json
    var jsonList = json.decode(response.body) as List;
    //hacemos un mapeo, pasamos cada elemento a un objeto negocio
    return jsonList.map((i) => new Negocio.fromJson(i)).toList();
  } else {
    // si se responde con error, lanzamos una excepción
    //para que pueda ser detectada por el builder
    throw Exception('Failed to load post');
  }
}
```

y el error que me sale es:

"type _InternallLinkedHasMap is not a subtype of type List  in type cast."

Que puede ser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es que el JSON que retorna no es un `Array`, sino un `Map`, primero tienes que obtener el Array del campo que deseas, en este caso es 'negocio', lo puedes hacer así :

```
 var jsonObject = json.decode(response.body);
 List jsonList = jsonObject["negocio"];
```